# Python Pandas: sorting by one columns and drop duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a dataframe with some duplicates but I can not just drop them all. There are four columns, one is title and the other are important information about molecules:

```
Title,docking score,glide rmsd,chiral flag
ligprep_2.maegz:1,-6.437,0.743,true
ligprep_2.maegz:1,-5.776,0.527,true
ligprep_2.maegz:2,-6.439,8.175,false
ligprep_2.maegz:2,-5.274,4.867,false
ligprep_2.maegz:3,-5.912,8.936,true
ligprep_2.maegz:3,-5.516,8.921,true
ligprep_2.maegz:4,-5.148,0.464,true
ligprep_2.maegz:4,-5.005,1.163,true
ligprep_2.maegz:5,-5.148,0.464,true
ligprep_2.maegz:5,-5.005,1.163,true
ligprep_2.maegz:6,-5.592,6.263,false
ligprep_2.maegz:6,-4.022,0.729,false
ligprep_2.maegz:7,-5.911,9.566,true
ligprep_2.maegz:7,-5.636,8.793,true
```

It is important to notice that I had 787 rows in these dataframe but there are only 477 molecules. For example, ligprep_2.maegz:1 from the first and the second row is the same thing but they have different configurations with different glide rmsd.

I would like to sort my rows by glide rmsd from the biggest one and then drop duplicates. I suspect there will be rows with the smallest glide rmsd.

I used this code:

```
TEST = data.sort_values(by="glide rmsd",ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset=['Title'], keep='first')
```

That worked but I got a strange result. Then I checked my data with command `TEST.describe()` I saw this:

```
docking score   glide rmsd
count   469.000000  469.000000
```

There are 469 rows but there must be 477 molecules (rows).

What did I do wrong?

**UPD:** molecules were lost not because of code!

Comment: Your code is probably good. It's not possible to find the error with this subset.

Try to compare `data` and `TEST` like that: 

`set(TEST["Title"]).symmetric_difference(set(data["Title"].drop_duplicates()))`

Comment: The result was ```set()```

Comment: You have 469 unique molecules only in your dataframe. You lost 8 molecules :-) (sorry, my question was stupid, obviously the answer would be `set()`!)

Comment: Check `len(data["Title"].unique())` is 469.

Comment: So, the result is truly is 469 and my code worked right. I suspect we have lost 8 molecules earlier ): Thank you a lot!